# Check if professors' and rooms' schedules have conflict

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to check if the professor has a scheduled subject for the time range or if a room is taken within the time range. Here is my schema:

```
| subjectcode | prof_id  | start               | end                 | room |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FREE ELEC 4 | 16-00002 | 2016-12-12T07:30:00 | 2016-12-12T10:30:00 | 1104 |
| TECHNO      | 16-00001 | 2016-12-12T11:00:00 | 2016-12-12T14:00:00 | 1103 |
| FREE ELEC 4 | 16-00002 | 2016-12-13T08:00:00 | 2016-12-13T10:00:00 | 1104 |
| TECHNO      | 16-00001 | 2016-12-13T10:30:00 | 2016-12-13T13:30:00 | 1103 |
| IT ELEC 5   | 16-00002 | 2016-12-13T15:30:00 | 2016-12-13T18:30:00 | 1106 |
| MMS         | 16-00003 | 2016-12-15T08:00:00 | 2016-12-15T10:00:00 | 1107 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have this query below:

```
SELECT batchid, subjectcode, prof_id, DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AS start, DATE_FORMAT(end, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AS end, room FROM schedules WHERE prof_id = "16-00002" OR room = "1103" OR start BETWEEN "2016-12-13T08:00:00" AND "2016-12-13T09:00:00" OR end BETWEEN "2016-12-13T08:00:00" AND "2016-12-13T09:00:00" OR "2016-12-13T08:00:00" BETWEEN start AND end
```

I would get this result:

```
| subjectcode | prof_id  | start               | end                 | room |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FREE ELEC 4 | 16-00002 | 2016-12-12T07:30:00 | 2016-12-12T10:30:00 | 1104 |
| TECHNO      | 16-00001 | 2016-12-12T11:00:00 | 2016-12-12T14:00:00 | 1103 |
| FREE ELEC 4 | 16-00002 | 2016-12-13T08:00:00 | 2016-12-13T10:00:00 | 1104 |
| TECHNO      | 16-00001 | 2016-12-13T10:30:00 | 2016-12-13T13:30:00 | 1103 |
| IT ELEC 5   | 16-00002 | 2016-12-13T15:30:00 | 2016-12-13T18:30:00 | 1106 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The result I would like to get that would match the date/time ranges from `2016-12-13T08:00:00` to `2016-12-13T09:00:00` having a prof_id of 16-00002 **OR** room of 1104:

```
| subjectcode | prof_id  | start               | end                 | room |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| FREE ELEC 4 | 16-00002 | 2016-12-13T08:00:00 | 2016-12-13T10:00:00 | 1104 |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm truthfully not completely clear on how you're looking to filter your `BETWEEN` conditions, though the main issue is that you're using `OR` for every condition. If any single one of the conditions is met, the record is returned. If you want *multiple* conditions to be true for the record to be returned, you'll need to use some grouped conditions and `AND`. See something like below...

```
SELECT 
  ...
FROM schedules 
WHERE 
  (prof_id = "16-00002" OR room = "1104") 
  AND 
  (start BETWEEN "2016-12-13T08:00:00" and "2016-12-13T09:00:00" 
  OR end BETWEEN "2016-12-13T08:00:00" and "2016-12-13T09:00:00" 
  OR "2016-12-13T08:00:00" BETWEEN start and end)
```

The above query will return all results where both A and B evaluate to true:

```
 A) Professor is 16-00002, OR the room is 1104
 B) "start" is between 2016-12-13T08:00:00 and 2016-12-13T09:00:00,
    OR "end" is between 2016-12-13T08:00:00 and 2016-12-13T09:00:00,
    OR 2016-12-13T08:00:00 is between "start" and "end"
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much! I didn't think that I can use that. I'll declare this as the answer in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I am not very well versed with mysql syntax but the general query would go something like this :

```
SELECT 
   batchid, subjectcode, prof_id, 
   DATE_FORMAT(start, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AS start, 
   DATE_FORMAT(end, '%Y-%m-%d %h:%i %p') AS end, 
   room 
FROM 
   schedules 
WHERE 
   (prof_id = "16-00002" OR room = "1104")
   and (start <= "2016-12-13T08:00:00" AND "2016-12-13T09:00:00"<=end)
```